# understanding parameterized queries php, sql, mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I was looking for information about parameterized queries, the problem is that I cant find basic examples to follow in `php`.

Is this correct?

**PHP**

```
 $email= $_POST["email"]; //or mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST["email"]);?
```

**SQL**

```
 SET @email = '$email';
 SELECT email FROM users WHERE email=@email
```

Whit this configuration would be enough to avoid sql injections?

Comment: No. If you're concatenating strings into a query string *at all* you're *not* using prepared statements and *you're vulnerable to SQL injection*.

Comment: So, to let this clear, the only way to avoid sql injection is by using prepared statements with mysqli or pdo?

Answer (score 1):

using bind_param is a way to avoid injection like such in php

```
$stmt = $dbConnection->prepare(' SELECT email FROM users WHERE email=?');
$stmt->bind_param('s', $email); // 's' is string

$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
//do something with $result
```

with what you asked in the comment, I think that might work, Im not sure off the top of my head. Another way for multiple in PDO is like

```
$stmt= $dbh->prepare('SELECT email, user, status, is_new 
                    FROM users 
                    WHERE email=:email 
                    AND user=:user 
                    AND status=:status 
                    AND is_new=:is_new');
$stmt->bindParam(':email ', $calories);
$stmt->bindParam(':user', $user);
$stmt->bindParam(':status', $status);
$stmt->bindParam(':is_new', $is_new);

$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Ok, I understand better, thank you. I have this question, if I want to use for example `email=? AND user=? AND status=? AND is_new=?` do I need to us `bind_param("ssss",$email,$user,$status,$is_new)`...4 "s" together?

Comment: If they are all strings then yes, otherwise you need to use the corresponding letter. Check the types part on the php documentation. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: @Dan I think so, I added another way that might work that way in my edit :)

Answer (score 0):

In this case you are open to SQL injection and you would need to use

```
mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST["email"]);
```

To insure that SQL Injection would not be possible. However using PDO would be another option. http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

I hope this helps.

Comment: Even mysqli_real_escape_string is not foolproof.

Comment: Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)